# Frequent "Debug: Destroying XDQPServerSession" messages in log files

Tags: marklogic

We are seeing Debug: Destroying XDQPServerSession log entries in our MarkLogic cluster.

> 2020-06-11 12:37:28.144 Debug: Destroying XDQPServerSession {client=ohcinmlp04.cams.cen.info,timestamp=15918925856853780,session=14750896137644680063,target=2887569106592314424,targets=(3119624861216817938,2796491349043070202,6212503532213277835,14162006363960283013),numaNode=0,expired,starttime=1591892605,timelimit=827,lifetime=843,idle=843,exception=15,reqcount=2,lastreq=eval} because SVC-EXTIME: Time limit exceeded

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this log and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An e-node operation can create an **XDQPServerSession** on each d-node it talks to
during the course of execution. Once per second, each MarkLogic node will execute a
test operation on that **XDQPServerSession** to make sure it can continue to serve
queries (i.e., we make sure the forests referenced by the session are
available), and also to check that the session hasn't been around too long
([SVC-EXTIME](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/messages/SVC-en/SVC-EXTIME)).

We can see `lastreq=eval` and `SVC-EXTIME: Time limit exceeded` in that log message, so it seems that you have a long-running eval transaction that has timed out.

What that specific message indicates is that the session was timed out
(SVC-EXTIME) because it had been running too long and that the session had not
been explicitly cleaned up by the client making the connection; so MarkLogic
cleans up to reclaim the memory.

If you see those messages occasionally, it is generally not something to worry about. That is why it is logged at the **Debug** level.

However, if you are seeing a large numbers of these messages, it may indicate that there is some sort of issue that requires attention.